# How to make the patch background move behind a turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a project to create a flight control simulator in NetLogo. I know the physics of a plane necessary for flight, but I don't understand how to incorporate that into code and how to create a turtle on a background of patches so that as I control the turtle (which performs the function of the plane) the background of patches moves (as if it were the sky). I don't know where to start especially with the coding. Any ideas, tips, hints? please.

Comment: Netlogo does not support the movement of patches. The patches must stay fixed. Still, you could move their colors, thus making it look like the background is moving.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I completely understand but it sounds like you want to move the turtle (you already know how) but want the turtle to stay in the center of the view and the background to move behind it.

I think you would control the turtle as you have planned, but if you want to visualize it as you are describing with the patches moving behind it, you need to call

```
follow turtle 0
```

Where `turtle 0` is the turtle you are moving as a plane.  This just needs to be called once in some setup routine.